# How to make CI/CD fail when the folder size is too large

Tags: continuous-integration, cicd

We must prevent the uncontrolled growth of a dependency folder via developers.

```bash
./check_size.sh --limit 3GB ./node_modules ./packages/*/node_modules
# ^ fail if limit was overtaken
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing `bash` is okay.
Something like this?

```
SIZE=`du -cs ./node_modules ./packagese/*/node_modules | cut -f 1 | tail -1`
if [ $SIZE -gt 3145728 ]; then
   echo 'Too big'
   exit 1
fi
```